# What is the sequence of 'create' and 'destroy' during plan phase?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

Just ran `terraform plan` and it spit out the config that needed to be run against GCP API. Per the plan, it has to destroy some entities and recreate them. These modules are not interdependent on each other. Sample output below.

Just wondering if the creation (in this case more like 'overwrite') happens before destruction or vice versa or is it completely random?

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------

An execution plan has been generated and is shown below.
Resource actions are indicated with the following symbols:
  + create
  - destroy

Terraform will perform the following actions:

  + module.project_01.google_project_service.project_service[0]
      id:                 <computed>
      disable_on_destroy: "true"
      project:            "proj-**"
      service:            "compute.googleapis.com"

  + module.project_01.google_project_service.project_service[1]
      id:                 <computed>
      disable_on_destroy: "true"
      project:            "proj-**"
      service:            "cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com"

  + module.project_01.google_project_service.project_service[2]
      id:                 <computed>
      disable_on_destroy: "true"
      project:            "proj-**"
      service:            "cloudbilling.googleapis.com"

  + module.project_01.google_project_service.project_service[3]
      id:                 <computed>
      disable_on_destroy: "true"
      project:            "proj-**"
      service:            "servicenetworking.googleapis.com"

  - module.project_01.google_project_service.project_service_billing

  - module.project_01.google_project_service.project_service_compute

  - module.project_01.google_project_service.project_service_crm


Plan: 4 to add, 0 to change, 3 to destroy.

------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

Terraform will automatically destroy resources before creating new ones in a `change` or `+-` situation where the resource cannot be updated. To quote the documentation:

> By default, when Terraform must make a change to a resource argument that cannot be updated in-place due to remote API limitations, Terraform will instead destroy the existing object and then create a new replacement object with the new configured arguments.

Terraform resources essentially will [CRUD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete), and have code written for each of the four actions. An update will be attempted in this `change` situation, but sometimes this is not possible due to API limitations. In those situations, a `destroy` is followed by a `create`.

However, there is the ability to `create_before_destroy` in a `lifecycle` block within the resource when no update code and/or API endpoint is available:

```
lifecycle {
  create_before_destroy = true
}
```

You can read more about this in the [lifecycle block documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/resources.html#lifecycle-lifecycle-customizations).

Comment: Thanks! So in this case if ```create_before_destroy``` is enabled, will it eventually end up destroying what it created? Or will it just destroy the old object while keeping the newly created object intact? The confusion for me I guess is if old and new object one and the same or are they different and if so in what aspect?

Comment: @aplusp In that situation the new resource will be created and then the old one destroyed, so the new one will remain intact. This is most useful in situations like AWS Security Groups.

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the specific answer with the example in the question in that there is no dependency order here so actually all 6 things will happen in parallel (assuming `-parallelism>=6` as per the default of 10).